# How to create a unique pointer pointing to unique pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, unique-ptr

I can create a unique pointer pointing to unique pointer;

The below code seems to work well.

```
auto as = make_unique<unique_ptr<int>> (make_unique<int>(3));
**as = 2;
cout << **as<<endl;
```

However, I am wondering how to create a unique pointer pointering to unique pointers.

Something like this:

```
unique_ptr<unique_ptr<int>[]>
```

I know I can use array `(array<unique_ptr<int>, num>)` or vector `(vector<unique_ptr<int>(num))`. But is it possible to create `unique_ptr<unique_ptr<int>[]>` using `make_unique` syntax?

Comment: `auto as = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<int>[]>(2); as[0] = std::make_unique<int>(1); as[1] = std::make_unique<int>(2);` ???

Comment: Since you want an array of `unique_ptr`s, I don't get why you do not prefer `st::array`. Please elaborate on more context about that part.

Comment: @LouisGo my friend, why context or purpose is always necessary? I think it is okay to wonder when you are learning something. I am just curious.

Comment: This suspiciously looks like a so-called "XY problem".